# R: How to properly use exists()

Tags: r

I have a list of lists. I have to run lapply on the list to do some work with each of the inner lists. The inner lists don't always have the same structure, so I try to do a check with exists, before proceeding:

```
innerlist <- list(foo="anotherfoo", bar="anotherbar", baz="baz")
if(exists("innerlist$baz")) cat("got a baz!!\n") #never prints anything!
```

What am I doing wrong?!! How do I check for the existence of a list attribute/item? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `exists` looks for variables and `innerlist$baz` is not a variable. `innerlist` is a variable. The `$` is actually a somewhat hidden function call. It's the same as

```
`$`(innerlist, baz)
```

so don't use `exists()` if you are checking for a key in a list.

If you want to check if a list has a key, you can either do

```
"baz" %in% names(innerlist)
# or
!is.null(innerlist$baz)
```

Comment: thank you so much. I didn't think of it as a find in list problem else I would have found the other question. Sorry for the duplicate :)